# Props in inheritance and composition

Tags: inheritance, reactjs, subclass, composition, subclassing

I have a React class named `Panel` that I would like to serve as a reusable component for various kinds of specific panels in a UI. Each panel has in common a title bar and a "Submit" button, but the body of each kind of panel is unique.

I could use either inheritance (sub-classing) or composition to achieve this, but which would be best in this case?

I have tried sub-classing, having a render method in the parent `Panel` and then having child panels override a `renderBody` method, which `render` uses. That seems to break down because each specific panel needs its own props (such as a "title"), and React complains when modified props are passed to `super` in a component constructor (the error message is, "When calling super() . . . make sure to pass up the same props that your component's constructor was passed."). Since the "title" is specific to a kind of panel, I don't want the end consumer having to specify a "title" prop itself.

```js
class Panel extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.title}</div>
        <div>{this.renderBody()}</div>
        <div><button>Submit</button></div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

class SomeSubPanel extends Panel {

  constructor(props) {
    // React throws the error message at the following line
    let newProps = Object.assign({}, props, {title: "Some Sub Panel"})
    super(newProps)
  }

  renderBody() {
    return (<div>Panel Body Goes Here</div>)
  }

}
```

Using composition wouldn't seem to be as tidy as sub-classing because each panel only needs to have a specific body, yet the body (which is HTML) can't be passed between components.

What would be the "React way" of having child components that can pass traits to a reusable parent component?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you post some of your code? The constructor for your sub-classes should be passing props to super, and I don't see why that would be an issue from the description alone.

Comment: The problem is that error message. The sub-class wants to adjust the "props" by adding a "title", but React doesn't allow props to be modified. I'll try to post some code.

Comment: I think that composition is generally preferred, especially in light of the fact that stateless react components are (all things being equal) generally seen to be preferable (for some definitions of preferable).

Comment: quick note about your code: you can't return multiple top level elements in render. you need to either wrap them in a parent div or return an array of them and give each a unique key

Comment: Adjusted sample code to be more correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely use composition. Generally, I don't think you should ever extend your own React components. Here's how you could achieve it:

```
class ReusablePanel extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{this.props.title}</div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onSubmit}>Submit</button>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class FootballPanel extends React.Component {
  handleSubmitButtonClick = () => {
    // do something
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ReusablePanel title='Football' onSubmit={this.handleSubmitButtonClick}>
        <div>{/* Football markup */}</div>
      </ReusablePanel>
    )
  }
}

class ArsenalPanel extends React.Component {
  handleSubmitButtonClick = () => {
    // do something
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ReusablePanel title='Arsenal' onSubmit={this.handleSubmitButtonClick}>
        <div>{/* Arsenal markup */}</div>
      </ReusablePanel>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Why "should you never extend your own React components"?

Comment: @MarioTacke I don't know about "never"... but extending components is confusing, imo. Using components just the way they are can achieve everything you do by subclassing without the extra noise and inheritance tree to follow.

Comment: Both answers given to this question are correct, but this was first and follows the question's given class paradigm. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 2):

I think the React way of doing this would simply be:

```
// using a function for brevity, but could be a class
let Panel = ({ title, handleSubmit, children }) =>
  <div>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    {children}
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
  </div>
```

Then elsewhere:

```
<Panel title="Foo" handleSubmit={onSubmit}>{specificChildContent}</Panel>
```